# How to clear cookies for old SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN in Django

Tags: django, session, cookies

We recently changed our cookie domain (settings.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN) from *domain.com* to *.domain.com* and this is now preventing Safari users from logging in unless they clear their cookies. The problem seeds to the fact that there's *sessionid* cookies set for both domains.

Is there a way to clear or ignore the original domain or is the only way to advice users to clear cookies?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can occur when the `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` setting is modified.  (You stated that `SESSION_COOKE_PATH` was changed).

The documentation for [`SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN) comes with this warning:

> SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN
>
> Be cautious when updating this setting on a production site. If you
>   update this setting to enable cross-domain cookies on a site that
>   previously used standard domain cookies, existing user cookies will be
>   set to the old domain. This may result in them being unable to log in
>   as long as these cookies persist.

This would occur if you went from:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
```

to

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.domain.com'
```

As you've stated, there are now two cookies on the client end which will be sent to the server during a request, with both cookies named `sessionid`.  When Django looks at the cookies, it only has access to a Python dictionary, so it only every sees one `sessionid` cookie rather than both that were sent.

I haven't tested this, but some ideas for fixing the problem may be:

- Ask the user to delete the appropriate cookies.  Depending on the number of users and their skill level, this may not be an reasonable option.  Asking them to delete ALL their cookies may be out of the question.
- Wait for the old cookies to expire.  By default, it appears as though the `sessionid` cookie has a 14 day expiry.  Once the old session cookies expire, they will no longer be sent with each request, allowing the new `sessionid` cookie to take effect.
- Change the name of the `sessionid` cookie and write a custom Django middleware to handle both old and new `sessionid` cookies.

I haven't tested the last point, but it should be possible to change the [`SESSION_COOKIE_NAME`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-name) to something other than `sessionid`.  Now, this will prevent existing logged in users from using their existing `sessionid` cookies, so you'd need to write a custom middleware which was capable of handling both `sessionid` cookies (for old cookies) and `sessionidnew` cookies for current logons.

Something like this will work:

```
from django.utils.importlib import import_module
from django.contrib.sessions import middleware
from django.conf import settings

class MySessionMiddleware(middleware.SessionMiddleware):
    def process_request(self, request):
        engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
        session_key = request.COOKIES.get(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME, None)
        if session_key is None:
            # Look for old cookie in request for auth purposes.
            session_key = request.COOKIES.get('sessionid', None)
        request.session = engine.SessionStore(session_key)
```

You'd have to replace the `SessionMiddleware` in `settings.py` under `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` with this new middleware. Eg: Change `'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'` to `'custommiddleware.MySessionMiddleware'` where custommiddleware.py is the file with above code and is present in your project root folder (where manage.py file is present)

Once enough time has passed and you're satisfied that all of the old `sessionid` cookies have expired, you could do the reverse and change back to using `sessionid` as the preferred cookie name for sessions, eventually removing the specialist code which can handle two different types of `sessionid` cookie.

Comment: Yeah, I meant ```SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN```, mistyped it as ```SESSION_COOKIE_PATH```. Changing the session cookie name is a neat trick and would work in this case. Thanks for pointing it out!