# Prevent Cookie Sharing across sub-domains

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Is there a way to prevent the cookie sharing on subdomains

Following is my session cookie domain

DJANGO_COOKIE_DOMAIN=.dev.fox.com

and my set_cookie() method sets the cookie even for subdomains like e.g: abc.fox.dev.com.

NOTE: I am getting this token via Firebase authentication.

I want to create an isolation , that if a user is logged in on app.dev.fox.com , cookies must be set on app.dev , but unfortunately it is set on all domains ending on .dev.fox.com

**Edit**: how to prevent it and make it dynamic, meaning if user log-in on app.dev cookie gets set on it only , and if they logs-in on abc.dev it get set on it ?

Comment: `DJANGO_COOKIE_DOMAIN`? Did you mean to write `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN`?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yes !

Comment: `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` should simply be `None` if you don't want cross domain cookies. Do note that changing this value can cause some trouble for existing users. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625569/how-to-clear-cookies-for-old-session-cookie-domain-in-django

Comment: Please don't add solutions into the question body, those are supposed to go in an answer. In the case of this question an appropriate answer is already present on the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dot prefix, so:

```
#        no leading dot 🖟
DJANGO_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'dev.fox.com'
```

so if your host runs on `app.fox.dev.com`, use:

```
#        no leading dot 🖟
DJANGO_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'app.dev.fox.com'
```

Comment: What if I set it to None ?

Comment: Will it behave in a way that the cookie will be set on the HOST initiating the request ?